# How to prescribe the width and the height of a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, menu, jlabel

I am making a game, and i'm in the menu, however, I have to put one button. And, to make this, I created a JLabel with one image, and I used the MouseListener, but I have to prescribe the proportion of this JLabel, how can I do this? Thanks for the answer, and sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a layout manager to control the position and size of the components. Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details
2. Use a `Border` (like `EmptyBorder`) to affect the "padding" to the label, which will change it's overall size.  Take a look at [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details
3. Consider using an undecorated button instead of a `JLabel`. See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

Comment: Can you give-me examples, plox? xD

Answer (score 0):

```
JLabel j = new JLabel();

j.setSize(x,y);
```

where X is the width in pixels and Y is the height in pixels.

Comment: I tried this mode, but I didn't make it, it continued with errors.

Comment: @IsaacReinaldo Could you post the code that you have?

Comment: Hi, thanks for read my text, but don't need more, I got the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

`JLabel#setPrefferedSize` is probably what you're looking for, but I recommend looking into Layout Managers that will set the size for you.